# Install Ubuntu along with Windows and Optimal partitioning?

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu as primary OS. How should I do the partitioning to get maximum output?

I am java/Liferay developer.

My system configuration is:

- dual core
- 4 gb ram.

Comment: What do mean with "maximum output"? As for partitioning is there is no "best way".

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you install windows first - Pretty thorough instruction right here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot. Just ignore the part that says "setup grub to boot windows" and it will boot to ubuntu